# button over button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a problem in my winform c# project.
In my project I have two main functions, one makes buttons at run time and the other function allows me to move the button on the form at run time. Now what can I do if I have button on other button so I made function that replace the button places as it was at the beginning but the function make problems if someone can help me it will be great!

```
public void upandunder(Button cBtn1, Button cBtn2)
    {
        if ((cBtn1.Location.X == cBtn2.Location.X) && (cBtn1.Location.Y == cBtn2.Location.Y))
        {
            int placex = cBtn1.Location.X;
            int placey = cBtn1.Location.Y;
            cBtn1.Location.X = cBtn2.Location.Y;
            cBtn1.Location.Y = cBtn2.Location.Y;
            cBtn2.Location.X = placex;
            cBtn2.Location.Y = placey;

        }
    }
```

Comment: its makes me that errorError 1 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable C:\Users\איתן יונה\Desktop\drawsquare2\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 172 17 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Start with changing `Button x, Button y` to `Button cBtn1, Button cBtn2`, will make your code *readable*...

Answer (score 1):

> its makes me that errorError  1   Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable

Correct, the return value of the `Location` property is not editable. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx):

> Because the `Point` class is a value type (`Structure` in Visual Basic, `struct` in Visual C#), it is returned by value, meaning accessing the property returns a copy of the upper-left point of the control. So, adjusting the `X` or `Y` properties of the `Point` returned from this property will not affect the `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, or `Bottom` property values of the control. To adjust these properties set each property value individually, or set the `Location` property with a new `Point`.

Therefore, you need to rewrite your code to the following:
(Also, I *strongly* recommend naming the parameters something other than `x` and `y`, since you're dealing with coordinates that have x and y values within the function...)

```
public void upandunder(Button btn1, Button btn2)
{
    if ((btn1.Location.X == btn2.Location.X) && (btn1.Location.Y == btn2.Location.Y))
    {
        Point originalLocation = btn1.Location;
        btn1.Location = btn2.Location;
        btn2.Location = originalLocation;
    }
}
```

or even better, just compare the two `Point` values as returned by the `Location` property (the `Point` structure [overloads the `==` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.op_equality.aspx)):

```
public void upandunder(Button btn1, Button btn2)
{
    if (btn1.Location == btn2.Location)
    {
        Point originalLocation = btn1.Location;
        btn1.Location = btn2.Location;
        btn2.Location = originalLocation;
    }
}
```

Of course, I fail to see how that accomplishes anything. First you check to see that the buttons are positioned on top of each other (have exactly the same x- and y-coordinates), and then if they do, you swap their positions. They're already *in* the same positions—you tested that before you executed the swapping code.

Judging by the name of your function (`upandunder`, which should be `UpAndUnder` following standard .NET naming conventions), it seems as if you wish to change the Z order of the buttons. If that's the case, then you should call either the [`BringToFront`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) or [`SendToBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback.aspx) methods of the button control.

Comment: its posibal to do if the buuton is tuching ather button they will change ther places?

Comment: the function doesnt work its just put the first button under the second button they need to change palce like it was in the beging if to x have x.location = 5,6; and y have y.loction = 9,6; yhey need to swich palces if the tuch and then x.loction = 9,6 and y.loction = 5,6;

Comment: @eit The buttons don't remember where they were before, they only know where they are *now*. As I've explained in my answer, your `if` statement checks to see that the buttons are currently position on top of each other, and if they are, it swaps their positions. That effectively does nothing. You'll need to save the position of the buttons in a member variable to re-use later if you want it.

Comment: ok now i think that i know what to do i will stay in tuch if its posibal :)?

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` Property on a Control returns a Point.  The Point structure has the X and Y values you're working with.  Instead of accessing them directly, I think you want to provide new Location points.

Give this a try (It works on my Machine)

```
public void UpAndUnder(Button cBtn1, Button cBtn2)
{
    if (cBtn1.Location == cBtn2.Location.Y)
    {                
        Point oldPoint = new Point(cBtn1.Location.X, cBtn1.Location.Y);
        cBtn1.Location = new Point(cBtn2.Location.X, cBtn2.Location.Y);
        cBtn2.Location = oldPoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place one button over other, just call

```
button1.BringToFront();
```

this will change Z-order of button1 and place it over all other controls.